# Variational Autoencoder in Keras: How to achieve different output of a Keras Layer at the time of training and prediction?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder, collaborative-filtering

We're implementing a paper titled - "**[Variational Autoencoders for Collaborative Filtering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05814.pdf)**" in TF 2.0.
The sample implementation of the above paper in TF 1.0 is given [here](https://github.com/dawenl/vae_cf/blob/master/VAE_ML20M_WWW2018.ipynb).

The paper proposes an implementation of a Variational Autoencoder for collaborative filtering. As the output of the encoder, it uses the **reparametrization trick** to sample the latent vector **Z** at the time of training the network.

The **reparametrization trick** samples ϵ ∼ N (0, IK) and reparametrize the latent vector Z as: 
**Zu = µϕ(xu ) + ϵ ⊙ σϕ(xu)** where µϕ and σϕ are calculated from the output of the encoder.

But, at the time of prediction, the paper proposes to use only **µϕ** for sampling **Z**.

In our implementation, we used a custom **tf.keras.layers.Layer** to sample the latent vector **Z**. The following is the code of the architecture:

```
class Reparameterize(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  """
  Custom layer.

  Reparameterization trick, sample random latent vectors Z from 
  the latent Gaussian distribution.

  The sampled vector Z is given by
  sampled_z = mean + std * epsilon
  """
  def call(self, inputs):
    Z_mu, Z_logvar = inputs

    Z_sigma = tf.math.exp(0.5 * Z_logvar)
    epsilon = tf.random.normal(tf.shape(Z_sigma))
    return Z_mu + Z_sigma * epsilon


class VAE:
  def __init__(self, input_dim, latent_dim=200):

    # encoder
    encoder_input = Input(shape=input_dim)
    X = tf.math.l2_normalize(encoder_input, 1)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    X = Dense(600, activation='tanh')(X)

    Z_mu = Dense(latent_dim)(X)
    Z_logvar = Dense(latent_dim)(X)

    sampled_Z = Reparameterize()([Z_mu, Z_logvar])

    # decoder
    decoder_input = Input(shape=latent_dim)
    X = Dense(600, activation='tanh')(decoder_input)
    logits = Dense(input_dim)(X)

    # define losses
    """
    custom loss function
    def loss(X_true, X_pred)
    """

    # create models
    self.encoder = Model(encoder_input, [Z_logvar, Z_mu, sampled_Z], name='encoder')
    self.decoder = Model(decoder_input, logits, name='decoder')

    self.vae = Model(encoder_input, self.decoder(sampled_Z), name='vae')
    self.vae.add_loss(kl_divergence(Z_logvar, Z_mu))

    # compile the model
    self.vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss, metrics=[loss])
```

Now, I am looking for a way to change the implementation of the custom **Reparameterize layer** at the time of prediction to use only **µϕ** (Z_mu) for sampling **Z** so as to achieve what is proposed by the paper mentioned above.

Or if there's another way of doing so in Tf 2.0, kindly recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
# create your VAE model
my_vae = VAE(input_dim = my_input_dim)
# Train it as you wish
# .....
```

When training is done, you could use it as follows:

```
inp = Input(shape = my_input_dim)
_, Z_mu,_ = my_vae.encoder(inp) # my_vae is your trained model, get its outputs
decoder_output = my_vae.decoder(Z_mu) # use the Z_mu as input to decoder
vae_predictor = Model(inp, decoder_output) # create your prediction time model
```

You could use the *vae_predictor* model now for predictions.